# How to restart the server in jupyter hub through command line?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel

I have an instance of Jupyter running in Jupyter hub where there was an option to start/restart server as shown below: 
[image]

I then changed the theme using the command

```
jt -t <theme name>
```

Now, I can't see the option to stop and restart my server in my home screen  [image]

Somebody please help me where I can find this option? 
I typed the below command in Jupyter terminal and it doesn't work.

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

Comment: normally you can do `jupyter notebook list` to see all of your running servers, then just take the port that's running on and do `jupyter notebook stop <port number>`

Answer (score 1):

This is now under the JupyterHub/Lab File menu at the bottom, "Hub Control Panel".

Selecting that option for me brings up the new version of the menu depicted in your image at the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/hub/home

HTH